# Validation NotBlank on a non nullable field

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-validator

I'm trying to validate a form that includes a field that absolutely cannot be empty or null. So in my model, it is defined like this:

```php
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $end;

    /**
     * @param string $end
     * @return Blabla
     */
    public function setEnd(string $end): Blabla
    {
        $this->end = $end;
        return $this;
    }
```

Here is the validation of this field in my form:

```php
    $builder
        ->add('end', TextType::class, [
            'label'       => 'blabla',
            'constraints' => [
                new Length([
                    'min'        => 3,
                    'minMessage' => 'Min {{ limit }} chars',
                ]),
                new NotBlank([
                    'message' => 'not null blabla',
                ]),
            ],
        ])
```

Here is the error I receive when I send a wrong input per example "multiple spaces" :
`Expected argument of type "string", "null" given at property path "end".`

I can correct this error by adding the possibility to receive a null in my setter

```php
    /**
     * @var string|null
     */
    private $end;

    /**
     * @param string|null $end
     * @return blabla
     */
    public function setEnd(?string $end=null): blabla
    {
        $this->end = $end;
        return $this;
    }
```

But I don't find it very coherent to allow a field to receive null only to validate it and prevent to set the field with null value.

Can't we do otherwise?

Comment: Make sure that your form is sending the correct data back to the controller. I use API-Platform, and I had several times similar problems, when I found that for example, the operation was expected to have a property like `someField` and I was sending a property like `some_field`. In such a case, I though I am sending the value, but the Symfony wasn't able to make a proper validation due to misspelling.

Answer (score 1):

When form is submitted, all empty values are set to `null` by default so you should either accept `null` in your setter or use `empty_data` to customise default value:

The model:

```php
    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    private string $end = ''; // Remember to initialise the field with empty string if you use typed properties

    public function setEnd(string $end): void
    {
        $this->end = $end;
    }
```

Form:

```php
$builder->add('end', TextType::class, [
    'label' => 'blabla',
    'empty_data' => '',
]);
```

Since `NotBlank` checks for empty string, you can still use it this way.
This works for some built-in fields like `TextType` but may still convert an empty string to `null` in other fields because DataTransformers are applied to `empty_data` too: [docs](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/text.html#empty-data)

> Form data transformers will still be applied to the empty_data value. This means that an empty string will be cast to null. Use a custom data transformer if you explicitly want to return the empty string.

If you want to costomize `null` handling in your form types, add a custom `DataTransformer` or implement `DataTransformerInterface` directly in your form type just like it's done in `TextType`: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/5.4/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/Type/TextType.php

Please note that I used some of modern PHP features (Attributes and typed properties) to make the code a bit shorter.